# Iphone: Where to release objects?

Tags: iphone, memory-management

where i should release objects: in method dealloc or viewDidUnload?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is to release them and set them to nil in both of those methods.

1. You need to release your objects in viewDidUnload since memory warnings can happen, and if your view doesn't have a superview then you should release your outlets to save memory. The framework will issue a viewDidLoad again if the view was unloaded.
2. You need to release your objects in dealloc, since viewDidLoad + viewDidUnload is not necessarily called.

Finally you need to set your variables to nil in both of the methods, to not be able to call release on them the second time.

Comment: but is it possible that if i release objects in both methods a BAD_ACCESS happens?

Answer (score 2):

A short answer for you question: dealloc()

A long and more complicated answer for your question: both

1. release any unused IBOutlets in viewDidUnload(). This method will be called when your device is running out of memory.
2. release any objects that the current view controller is responsible for memory management, and release them in dealloc(). (An autoreleased object doesn't belong to this category)

Answer (score 1):

Any objects allocated and/or retained as part of `loadView` and/or `viewDidLoad` should be released in `viewDidUnload`. Releasing anything you alloc in `viewDidLoad` is easy to grasp, `loadView` is a bit harder if you are using a NIB. Any `IBOutlet` that is a property defined as `retain` will be implicitly retained as part of `loadView`.

If the view have for example a subview that is a `UITextField` and you connect this view to a property defined as:

```
 @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* nameField;
```

Then the actual text field when loaded from the NIB will have a retain count of +2. +1 because of it's parent view, and +1 because of the property you connected it too. Thus it's memory is not freed until the view controller is released, or the NIB is loaded again.

Unfortunately `viewDidUnload` is not called when a view controller is deallocated. So you must explicitly release all your `IBOutlets here as well. I use this patter in order to not forget to release anything:

```
-(void)releaseOutlets {
  // Set all outlets to nil
}

-(void)viewDidUnload {
    [self releaseOutlets];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [self releaseOutlets];
    // Release anything else.
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: but is it possible that if i release objects in both methods a BAD_ACCESS happens?

Comment: xger86x: It is possible if you do not also set the reference to nil in viewDidUnload.

Answer (score 0):

dealloc this way if the parent object is released the child objects will be released as well.

Comment: but why sometimes objects are released in viewDidUnload?

Comment: This is called when your running out of memory so it gives you the chance release visual things you are not using anymore like images to save memory and keep hold of data related to the object.